# MediaType for docx file

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I want to display a `docx`-file on my browser. But I am having problem with the media type for `docx`-file.

This is my sample code:

```
@RequestMapping("/view")
public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<byte[]> view(@RequestParam(value = "fileId") int id) throws IOException {

    FileDaoImplement fdi = new FileDaoImplement();
    Files f = fdi.getFile(id);
    byte[] document = f.getByte();

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType("What should I use to show a docx file??");
    header.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=");
    header.setContentLength(document.length);
    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(document, header);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try with specifying the `Mediatype` your request produces.

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/view", produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

not sure if you can get it to work with a `byte[]`, but you could use `Resource` as return-type instead like:

```
  @GetMapping(path = "/word", produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
  public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<Resource>  words() throws IOException {
     return new HttpEntity<Resource>(new ClassPathResource("/static/hello word.docx"));
  }
```